# Wait for completion of SP.RequestExecutor

Tags: 2013, javascript, web-services, sharepoint-addin, spservices

I am using SP.RequestExecutor to add attachments to a list item.

 I followed [Can't upload a non-text file to SharePoint App via REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60417/cant-upload-a-non-text-file-to-sharepoint-app-via-rest-api) 
I need to wait the completation of the asynch call of executeAsync method.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks,Nk

Comment: I tried to use $.when and then .done() but seems that the executeAsync method does not return a Deferred or Promise obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a deferred with a resolve for your return value that is populated during async execution. After that you return a promise that you catch in a done method on function calling (check jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/):

```
functionToCall().done(function (returnedValue) {
    // do something with the returned value
});

function functionToCall() {

    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {

        var valueToReturn = clientContext.get_web();

        clientContext.load(valueToReturn);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                dfd.resolve(valueToReturn);
            },
            function (sender, args) {
                //throw an error
            });
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: I need to use it inside a reader.onload and is seems hava some problems