# Bad Request 400 when uploading file to Sharepoint Online document library

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online, rest, office365apis

I am trying to upload a file to a document library and keep getting a statusCode of 400 with the text just saying "Bad Request." I was rifling through some other forums and saw that the API could potentially not have the right permissions but I haven't been able to figure out how to even check that, let alone set it to have full control.

Additionally, the site where the document library lives is a subsite, so I'm not sure if that has an effect on what I'm trying to do but I haven't seen an example where the library lives in a subsite to know if it does affect anything.

Here is my code, site name removed for client privacy, (largely taken from [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60417/cant-upload-a-non-text-file-to-sharepoint-app-via-rest-api)):

```
function dofunc() {
    var control = document.getElementById("elementIDHere");
    control.addEventListener("change", fdocattach, false);
}

var file;
var contents;

function fdocattach(event) {
    var i = 0,
    files = event.srcElement.files,
    len = files.length;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        console.log("Filename: " + files[i].name);
        console.log("Type: " + files[i].type);
        console.log("Size: " + files[i].size + " bytes");
    }

    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert("The FileSystem APIs are not fully supported in this browser.");
        return false;
    }           

    if (files.length > 0) {
        file = files[0];
        fileName = file.name;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = fonload;

        reader.onerror = function(event) {
            console.error("File reading error " + event.target.error.code);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }       
    return false;
}

function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
    var binary = ''
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer)
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i])
    }
    return binary;

}

function fonload(event) {
    contents = event.target.result;
            $.getScript("sitename/subsite/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", fonload2);
}

function fonload2() {
    var contents2 = _arrayBufferToBase64(contents);

    var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor("sitename/subsite");
    createitem.executeAsync({
        url: "sitename/subsite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/documentLibraryName')/Files/add(url='" + file.name + "',overwrite=true)",
        method: "POST",
        binaryStringRequestBody: true,
        body: contents2,
        success:  fsucc,
        error: ferr
        state: "Update"
    });

    function fsucc(data)
    {
        alert('success');
    }       
    function ferr(data)
    {
        alert('error\n\n' + data.statusText + "\n\n" + data.responseText);
    }       
}
```

Comment: From where are running this code? From sharepoint page itself or from some remote page?

Comment: From a sharepoint list form

Answer (score 0):

So you need to authenticate yourself before you can make call to office365 or sharepoint online.

For .Net CSOM you can refer following to authenticate yourself:

http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2013/03/18/connecting-to-office-365-using-client-side-object-model-and-web-services/

In javascript you can follow the following link to authenticate yourself:

[.NET and JavaScript libraries for Office 365 APIs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2014/05/12/net-and-javascript-libraries-for-office-365-apis/).

Comment: links provided in answer are broken. Fixed second link, first link still broken.